# trigger with arbitrary width

Tags: eventtrigger, counting-sort

Well, I'm trying to make a module in VHDL language, so far I have the internal clock (100MHz) and a control signal called IN (std_logic), and I need an output signal OUT (std_logic) of arbitrary width, said wide I want to control counting the clock rising_edge, I don't have a good programming base, that's why I'm stuck with this, if anyone can help me I thank you
  I enclose an illustrative image of how I wish to have the output, where delta / \ is an arbitrary interval that does not depend on the IN input, when IN goes low, the OUT signal must remain on until the counter finishes its purpose..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShkZp.jpg

Comment: Can you try something ? Post your entity and I will correct it if it's wrong. Does your delta will be constant ?

Comment: Firstable https://imgur.com/a/Iw6Ib0G, in this picture yo can see clock 100MHz, the signal "comienza_trigar" is the "master" in this situation, when this signal is rising edge, my out signal called "salida_prf" must to follow until the the time I want it. for example until 500 us., the signal flag is only there to control the in signal

Comment: my function delta will be variable could be 300 us, 32 ms, it depends of the situation dear friend, at the moment I dont have an specific code because I dont have such idea how to do it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WfVldmZ this is my code at the moment. :)

Comment: Your process is not good. If you want to have a sequential process, you must put only clock (and eventually reset) in sensitivity list. And *if rising_edge(clk)* must take in all the rest of your code.

Comment: thanks man, but the IN signal, is independent of clock, I think in this situation the only signal depending of clock is the counter. I did some change in my code and I tested with all the situation and it works. :) sorry my programming is very amateur because my base is too weak

Comment: If you want to self-answer your question, you are very welcome to do so. However, answers go in **answers** not in the question. Like your two earlier "edits" to the question, which you posted as answers, post the code you have as such as well.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically what to create an off delay?

**Note:** VHDL 2008 migth apply (my usual language)

```vhdl
entity off_delay is 
   generic(
      n : natural : 2 -- off delay
   );
   port(
      clk : in  std_logic;
      a   : in  std_logic;
      b   : out std_logic
   );
end entity;
```

clk _/¯\__/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\
a   _____/¯¯¯\________________________________
b   _________/¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\___________________

```vhdl
architecture synkron of off_delay is 
   signal delay: std_logic_vector(n downto 0); -- 1+n cycles out signal
begin 
   b <= delay(0);

   process(clk)
   begin
      if rising_edge(clk) then
         delay <= (others => '1') when a else ('0' & delay(delay'left downto 1));
      end if;
   end process;   
end architecture;
```

clk _/¯\__/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\_/¯\
a   _____/¯¯¯\_____________________________
b   _____/¯\¯\¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\___________________

```vhdl
architecture asynkron of off_delay is 
   signal delay: std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0); -- n cycles off delay
begin 
   b <= delay(0) or a;

   process(clk)
   begin
      if rising_edge(clk) then
         delay <= (others => '1') when a else ('0' & delay(delay'left downto 1));
      end if;
   end process;

end architecture;
```

**Note:** The asynkron solution will be dependent on stable `a` as it will be susceptible to glitches.

**Note:** The asynkron solution will introduce a delta delay that might be hard to debug

**Note:** Those are the simplest soulutions. To get technical a SR latch could be implemented to set by `a` in an asynkron fassion and reset by the synkron delay line. ***OBS* *Latches* *are* *strongly* *adviced* *against* *in* *fpga* *design!***

Comment: I really apreciate your help, my problem to result is more like your first draw, when signal IN is up or coming to the module, the signal OUT must be up and the falling edge of this signal (OUT) should be control by a counter as long as I want to be, for example: I want the OUT signal to be up for 300 us and then shut down. I am very sorry for my weak language. About your code above, the n is related to the long of my delay? out_sig is referred to the out signal for this porpuse? or at the end I must to concatenate the delay and OUT? also I can see at then and end if.

Comment: I made a update to the post so the fist part of your comment i didn't get :) A 300 us delay. Should as you say be implemented with a counter solution. Did not get that the delay was so long.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which use more ressources with a low width but less with a high width and with width as an input instead of generic :

```
entity top is
port
(
    i_rst   : in std_logic;
    i_clk   : in std_logic;
    i_din   : in std_logic;
    i_width : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    o_dout  : out std_logic
);
end top;

architecture Behavioral of top is

    signal counter  : unsigned(7 downto 0);
    signal oe       : std_logic;

begin

    process(i_clk)
    begin

        if i_rst = '1' then

            counter <= (others => '0');
            oe      <= '0';

        elsif rising_edge(i_clk) then

            if oe = '1' then
                counter <= counter + 1; 
                if counter = unsigned(i_width) - 1 then
                    counter <= (others => '0'); 
                    oe      <= '0';
                end if;
            elsif i_din = '1' then
                if unsigned(i_width) > x"01" then
                    counter <= counter + 1;            
                    oe      <= '1';
                end if;
            end if;

        end if; 

    end process;

    o_dout  <= oe or i_din;


end Behavioral;
```

But as Halfow told you, use combinational just before the output makes your module very sensitive to glitches.